# Accepting international datetime input in php

Tags: php, datetime, localization, internationalization

I'm currently adding support for internationalisation to a system written in PHP.  All dates are now stored as UTC, and displayed according to individual user localisation preferences.

However when a user inputs a date time (such as to specify a certain time window), the date time they input gets interpreted as a UTC datetime, not their local datetime.  For the internationalisation to be complete the system needs to assume that a datetime entered by the user refers to their local time.

How do I convert a date string (ie 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM') into a unix timestamp for the correct localisation?

- Further Clarification -
  All dates in database = UTC Timestamps
  All HTML Pages display users local time (as defined in their settings)
  HTML form has date that defaults to current local time
  PHP must treat that date time as local not UTC
  PHP must convert this local date timestring into UTC timestamp

Comment: Well you question does not have a very direct answer. You need to store the users GMT in the db so that you can use it for time conversions

Comment: Check out the localtime() function on the php website http://php.net/manual/en/function.localtime.php

Comment: @yankitwizzy Perhaps I wasn't clear.  Yes I'm storing the timestamps as UTC.  Timestamps are always UTC by definition.  That is already okay.  What I'm having problems with is accepting user input in that users localisation.

Comment: @SOliver I've looked, but that function converts a timestamp into an array.  What I need to do is turn a string of a datetime in what ever the users local time is, into a UTC timestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you know the timezone of the user, which he presumably chose in the preferences somewhere:

```
$timezone = new DateTimeZone($usersTimezone);
$datetime = new DateTime('2012-01-18 20:00:00', $timezone);
echo $datetime->getTimestamp();
```

This requires a recent version of PHP with [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).

Comment: This has got me on the right track, but the dates seem to end up adding the timezone offset twice.  For example if my location is set to 'Europe/Paris' the default times shown on the form correctly display 1 hour ahead of UTC/GMT (ie I'd currently be in CET).  But when I submit those times and process them with you code above, save the resulting UTC timestamps, they appear to add an extra hour again when I saved them.  Its as if the DateTime treats the user input string as if its UTC and not their local time defined by the DateTimeZone object?

Comment: Actually my mistake.  The timestamp was being translated back into a string before inserting into the database, so your solution works as advertised.  I just had to temporarily set default timezone to UTC in the function that creates the sql date strings, then restore the users setting before returning the string.